How can I get the value from my component using vue js
I have a problem getting the data from my text field compenent
AddUnitModal.vue
<CustomInput
  label="Unit Name"
  inputId="unit"
  :required="true"
  v-model="unitName"
  :errors="errors.name"
  @input="handleValue"
/>

data() {
    return {
      unitName: '' as string,
      errors: {} as Record<string, string>, // Initialize errors object
    };
  },
methods: {
     handleValue(value: string) {
      console.log(value);
      this.unitName = value;
    }
}

when showing the value in log it will show the text that I input and followed by something like this:
test //here is the text that I Inputed and the message below is shown next to it and will be stored to "unitName"
AddUnitModal.vue:117 
InputEvent {isTrusted: true, _vts: 1714439976907, data: 's', isComposing: false, inputType: 'insertText', …}
isTrusted
: 
true
_vts
: 
1714439976907
bubbles
: 
true
cancelBubble
: 
false
cancelable
: 
false
composed
: 
true
currentTarget
: 
null
data
: 
"s"
dataTransfer
: 
null
defaultPrevented
: 
false
detail
: 
0
eventPhase
: 
0
inputType
: 
"insertText"
isComposing
: 
false
returnValue
: 
true
sourceCapabilities
: 
null
srcElement
: 
input#unit.text-sm.p-2.text-blackpearl.rounded.w-full.border-2.mb-2
target
: 
input#unit.text-sm.p-2.text-blackpearl.rounded.w-full.border-2.mb-2
timeStamp
: 
2574
type
: 
"input"
view
: 
null
which
: 
0
[[Prototype]]
: 
InputEvent

TextInput.vue
<input v-model="inputValue" :id="inputId" :type="type" @input="updateValue($event.target.value)" class="text-sm p-2 text-blackpearl rounded w-full border-2 mb-2">

export default {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    inputId: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "text"
    },
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    errors: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: this.value
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(newValue) {
      this.inputValue = newValue;
      this.$emit('input', newValue);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    value(newValue) {
      this.inputValue = newValue;
    }
  }
};

I am trying to store my input text to "unitName". and is there a work around to store it directly to "unitName" without using this:
handleValue(value: string) {
      console.log(value);
      this.unitName = value;
    }


Isn't it supposed to be $value in the handleValue function? Also why doing v-model="unitName" if you are already have the same side-effect in your method?
